# invertible elements of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2＋1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I would like to determine the invertible elements of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$$[x]/(x^2＋1)$.

This ring is just finite ring, and all the elements are

{$0,1,2,x,x＋1,x＋2,2x,2x＋1,2x＋2$}. But I don't know hot to know which is invertible.

Another approach may be like the case of $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2＋2)$, this ring is isom
to  $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$×$\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ ( because $x^2＋2＝x^2-1＝(x＋1)(x-1)$, and Chinese reminder theorem), so there are 4 units.
But in the titled case, I cannot find easy isomorphism to another easier ring.

Comment: It turns out that this ring is actually a field. But if you don't have the tools to identify it as such, the simplest course of action is brute force. As you correctly observed, there are only nine elements. Checking them out one by one is easy. For example $x^2=-1$ so $x$ is invertible. Hop to it!

Comment: Thank you ! Could you tell me the proof how to prove this ring is a field?

Comment: Either brute force or suitable fact about quotient rings of polynomial rings. It depends on what you know already. If this does not ring a bell, I recommend brute force.

Comment: The quotient ring is a field when the polynomial is irreducible

Comment: You could think of the field as $\dfrac{\mathbb Z}{3\mathbb Z} [i]$, where $i^2=-1$

Comment: to find $\dfrac 1{i+1}$, for example, multiply top and bottom by $-i+1$

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**"But in the titled case, I cannot find easy isomorphism to another easier ring."

**Answer:** A quotient ring $k[x]/(f(x))$ is a field iff $f(x)\in k[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial which is iff $f(x)$ has no roots in $k$. In your case it follows (let $f(x):=x^2+1$)

$$f(0)=1, f(1)=2, f(2)=2^2+1=5=2$$

hence $f(x)$ has no roots in $k$ and hence $k[x]/(f(x))$ is a field.